# Slightly confused over particulars of explicitly declaring interface with member

Tags: c#, interface

I started with this:

```
interface IFoo
{
    string X { get; set; }
}

class C : IFoo
{
    public void F()
    {
    }
    string IFoo.X { get; set; }
}
```

It compiled as I was expecting.  No surprise.

Then I go to this:

```
interface IFoo
{
    string X { get; set; }
}

class C : IFoo
{
    public void F()
    {
        X = "";
    }
    string IFoo.X { get; set; }
}
```

Now I get 'X is not available in the current context'.

Wasn't expecting that.

I end up with:

```
interface IFoo
{
    string X { get; set; }
}

class C : IFoo
{
    public void F()
    {
        X = "";
    }
    private string X;
    string IFoo.X { get; set; }
}
```

And I never would have thought of that.

Question: The above code in not meshing with my current understanding of thigns because I see two X's.  On an intuitive level I can see the compiler doesn't need to get confused.  Can someone put it in their words the rules of the language at play here?

Thanks in advance.

Update after answer: I could have casted to the interface as below:

```
interface IFoo
{
    string X { get; set; }
}

class C : IFoo
{
    public void F()
    {
        (IFoo(this)).X = "";
    }
    string IFoo.X { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you've implemented your interface explicitly (by writing `string IFoo.X` instead of just `string X`), you can only access that interface property via the interface.

So you'd need to do

```
public void F()
{
    ((IFoo)this).X = "";
}
```

Or not declare the interface explicitly, i.e.

```
public string X { get; set; }
```

Comment: I've always felt it a bummer that '.' keeps it's high precedence in this particular case, it would be nice to just go (IFoo)this.X

Comment: Yeah, or even have a separate operator like they do in C++ (which I seem to remember was ->, e.g. `(IFoo)this->X`)

Answer (score 3):

An explicit interface implementation is not a regular named member of the class, and cannot be accessed by name on the class type (unless you cast it to the interface)

See the [spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664591%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Your explicit implementation of IFoo.X basically limits the use of IFoo.X to cases where the instance of C is treated as an IFoo. If you remove the explicit implementation, you'll get a property X that satisfies the IFoo interface, and can be used when treating the class as a C as well as an IFoo.